# Remove "?" from RadWindow content

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radwindow

So, how to remove this icon from RadWindow content? Is it able to remove that?
[image]

Here is my aspx code for delete confirmation.

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteCommandColumn" ConfirmText="Are you sure want to send this deletion for Approval?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ButtonType="FontIconButton" CommandName="Delete" />

<telerik:RadWindowManager RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="DeleteConfirmation" runat="server" Width="500px" Height="250px" Modal="true" Behaviors="Close, Move" EnableShadow="true" />
```

And, how to resize the radwindow, because the width and height not working.

Thanks for your help!:)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the questionmark font icon which is used with the Lightweight render mode using the following CSS class:

```
.RadWindow .rwConfirmDialog:before {
    content: "" !important;
}
```

or

```
.RadWindow .rwConfirmDialog:before {
    content: none !important;
}
```